# When Create Invoice Give error Like "Transaction has been declined. Please try again later." In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, invoice, amazon-payment

I have to configure the Amazone pay Payment Method then place an order using amazon-pay successfully after the admin side creates an invoice but gives an error like "Transaction has been declined. Please try again later" .[image]

also, the check-in log file gives an error

```
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidAuthorizationStatus</Code>
    <Message>Authorization xxxxxx is currently in Closed state. Capture can only be requested in Open state.</Message>
  </Error>
```

Comment: check error log

Comment: yes check and add error log in body part.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem on one of the projects and it appeared, that there is an undocumented feature in the module.

The [documentation](https://amzn.github.io/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/flow.html#payment-capture) states that one must create an invoice, but it actually sends capture requests **on creating a shipment** as well, once it's configured as *Charge on Shipment*.

In this case all subsequent capture requests fail and it's not possible to create an online invoice anymore.

So the solution for our customer was to created invoiced before creating shipments.

I hope this helps.